# Custom fonts with android studio is not working on devices

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

I'm trying to apply a custom fonts on my android app not only a few widgets also whole texts.

So I made a font resource directory and added font file (`.otf` but I have tried also `.ttf`),

```
custom-font-family.xml
```

And then, I added font_style.xml in value directory referenced by App Theme of style.xml

So I could saw it is working in preview...

But in my real device, It is not working!!

It display basic font of device setting.

my code is here

```
/font/nanum_barun_pen_font_family.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!--For API 26 ++ -->
<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"
    android:font="@font/nanumbarunpenr" />

<!--For under API 26-->
<font
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400"
    app:font="@font/nanumbarunpenr"/>
</font-family>
```

```
/res/value/font_style.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Custom font 적용 -->
    <style name="customTextViewFontStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nanum_barun_pen_font_family</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customButtonFontStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nanum_barun_pen_font_family</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customEditTextFontStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nanum_barun_pen_font_family</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customRadioButtonFontStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nanum_barun_pen_font_family</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customCheckboxFontStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nanum_barun_pen_font_family</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nanum_barun_pen_font_family</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

/res/values/style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!--Apply custom font-family-->
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/customTextViewFontStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/customButtonFontStyle</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/customEditTextFontStyle</item>
        <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/customRadioButtonFontStyle</item>
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/customCheckboxFontStyle</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

gradle

```
...
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
    GsonVersion = '2.8.6'
    retrofitVersion = '2.7.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
...
```

I tried apply this way on new empty android project.(same sdk version) but It is working well on this..

I don't know why it is not working only this app!!

Finally, I tried apply font-family directly, it was same.

Why !?!?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TextView` then change your `TextView` to  `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.` And should work.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I use androidx, so I cannot inflate android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.
And I tried use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView, but still not change.....